# php comparing two numbers together

Tags: php, function, comparison, numbers

Does PHP have some kind of function that will compare the numbers? I know they have text comparison like `similar_text()` But say I want to compare lat/lng values, and they're very similar but very slight difference

example :

```
place 1 

lat: 34.095161
lng: -117.720638

compare with

lat: 34.0948841
lng: -117.7206854

place 2

lat: 34.094572563643
lng: -117.72184828904

compare with 

lat: 34.094112
lng: -117.7250746
```

They maybe very close to each other which I want to be able to get a certain range? Is there some PHP function I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `round()` them to whatever degree of accuracy you want?

Comment: `similar_text` computes a sort of "distance" between two strings. For numbers, the equivalent is [`abs($lat1 - $lat2)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php).

Comment: @Interrobang I'm not trying to round the number because rounding lat and lng will result in undesirable results

Comment: @ruakh I don't see why absolute value will be similar to `similar_text` although, that is helpful to me getting an absolute value and I can check a range, but the way you word your statement seems like absolute value will give you a comparison between the two numbers which is not true.

Comment: @andrewliu: The absolute value of the *difference* between two numbers *is* a comparison between them. The larger that absolute value, the greater the distance.

Comment: @ruakh, I see what you're getting at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in function. Maybe you could use an Euclidian distance to compute their similarity is an easy-to-implement way.

```
$diff = sqrt((($lat1 - $lat2) * ($lat1 - $lat2)) + (($lng1 - $lng2) * ($lng1 - $lng2)));
$epsilon = 0.0001;
if ($diff < $espilon) {
    echo 'we consider them equal';
} else {
    echo 'they are different';
}
```

NB : $diff is here a pure quantification of difference, you cannot consider lat/lng values as forming 2D points whose distance can be compute through Euclidian approach stricto sensu (see [here why](http://sgowtham.net/blog/2009/08/04/php-calculating-distance-between-two-locations-given-their-gps-coordinates/))

Comment: Using `pow` is usually slower than multiplying the two values together. I'd recommend changing your first line to `sqrt((($lat1 - $lat2) * ($lat1 - $lat2)) + (($lng1 - $lng2) * ($lng1 - $lng2)))`. The result is less readable but usually faster. =)

Comment: I believe this would give me a idea of how to go about my code... Thanks

Comment: Not for another while, at the rate I'm going. =)

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). Usually used to see how big is the distance between 2 points on a sphere.